# How to convert a file to stream using just the file path in javascript on the browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, ionic-native

been trying to convert a file to a stream in the browser.
Am working on some ionic2 project and i don't seem to find a way to do so.
Ionic's file plugin can return either a binary string or an array buffer and i don't seem to know how to convert those to a stream either.
Any help ?

Comment: I suppose you can use the `input` with `type=file` to allow user to upload a file. Any particular reason for not doing so?

Comment: Actually i need to get metadata for a bunch of music files and the plugin am using requires the files stream

Comment: You could get the metadata on an input with `file=type` as such: `document.getElementById('myFile').files[0]`

Comment: try something like
`this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(filePath, fileName)
                .then(val => {
                    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(val)], { type: mediaType });})`

Comment: @Pablo actually I need to convert to a file stream